# Azure EventHubs throws Exception: At least one receiver for the endpoint is created with epoch of '0', and so non-epoch receiver is not allowed

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

### Introduction

Hello all, we're currently working on a microservice platform that uses Azure EventHubs and events to sent data in between the services.
Let's just name these services: CustomerService, OrderService and MobileBFF.

The CustomerService mainly sends updates (with events) which will then be stored by the OrderService and MobileBFF to be able to respond to queries without having to call the CustomerService for this data.

All these 3 services + our developers on the DEV environment make use of the same ConsumerGroup to connect to these event hubs.

We currently make use of only 1 partition but plan to expand to multiple later. (You can see our code is already made to be able to read from multiple partitions)

### Exception

Every now and then we're running into an exception though (if it starts it usually keeps throwing this error for an hour or something). For now we've only seen this error on DEV/TEST environments though.

The exception:

```
Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.EventHubsException(ConsumerDisconnected): At least one receiver for the endpoint is created with epoch of '0', and so non-epoch receiver is not allowed. Either reconnect with a higher epoch, or make sure all epoch receivers are closed or disconnected.
```

All consumers of the EventHub, store their SequenceNumber in their own Database. This allows us to have each consumer consume events separately and also store the last processed SequenceNumber in it's own SQL database. When the service (re)starts, it loads the SequenceNumber from the db and then requests events from here onwards untill no more events can be found. It then sleeps for 100ms and then retries. Here's the (somewhat simplified) code:

```
var consumerGroup = EventHubConsumerClient.DefaultConsumerGroupName;
string[] allPartitions = null;
await using (var consumer = new EventHubConsumerClient(consumerGroup, _inboxOptions.EventHubConnectionString, _inboxOptions.EventHubName))
{
    allPartitions = await consumer.GetPartitionIdsAsync(stoppingToken);
}

var allTasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (var partitionId in allPartitions)
{
    //This is required if you reuse variables inside a Task.Run();
    var partitionIdInternal = partitionId;

    allTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                await using (var consumer = new EventHubConsumerClient(consumerGroup, _inboxOptions.EventHubConnectionString, _inboxOptions.EventHubName))
                {
                    EventPosition startingPosition;
                    using (var testScope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
                    {
                        var messageProcessor = testScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<EventHubInboxManager<T, EH>>();
                        //Obtains starting position from the database or sets to "Earliest" or "Latest" based on configuration
                        startingPosition = await messageProcessor.GetStartingPosition(_inboxOptions.InboxIdentifier, partitionIdInternal);
                    }

                    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        bool processedSomething = false;
                        await foreach (PartitionEvent partitionEvent in consumer.ReadEventsFromPartitionAsync(partitionIdInternal, startingPosition, stoppingToken))
                        {
                            processedSomething = true;

                            startingPosition = await messageProcessor.Handle(partitionEvent);
                        }

                        if (processedSomething == false)
                        {
                            await Task.Delay(100, stoppingToken);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log error / delay / retry
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown on the following line:

```
await using (var consumer = new EventHubConsumerClient(consumerGroup, _inboxOptions.EventHubConnectionString, _inboxOptions.EventHubName))
```

### More investigation

The code described above is running in the MicroServices (which are hosted as AppServices in Azure)

Next to that we're also running 1 Azure Function that also reads events from the EventHub. (Probably uses the same consumer group).

According to the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#consumer-groups it should be possible to have 5 consumers per consumer group. It seems to be suggested to only have one, but it's not clear to us what could happen if we don't follow this guidance.

We did do some tests with manually spawning multiple instances of our service that reads events and when there were more then 5 this resulted in a different error which stated quite clearly that there could only be 5 consumers per partition per consumer group (or something similar).

Furthermore it seems like (we're not 100% sure) that this issue started happening when we rewrote the code (above) to be able to spawn one thread per partition. (Even though we only have 1 partition in the EventHub). ***Edit: we did some more log-digging and also found a few exception before merging in the code to spawn one thread per partition.***

Comment: Have you tried using a non default consumer group? or using a different consumer group per reader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That exception indicates that there is another consumer configured to use the same consumer group and asserting exclusive access over the partition.  Unless you're explicitly setting the `OwnerLevel` property in your client options, the likely candidate is that there is at least one `EventProcessorClient` running.

To remediate, you can:

- Stop any event processors running against the same Event Hub and Consumer Group combination, and ensure that no other consumers are explicitly setting the `OwnerLevel`.
- Run these consumers in a dedicated consumer group; this will allow them to co-exist with the exclusive consumer(s) and/or event processors.
- Explicitly set the `OwnerLevel` to 1 or greater for these consumers; that will assert ownership and force any other consumers in the same consumer group to disconnect.
  *(note: depending on what the other consumer is, you may need to test different values here.  The event processor types use 0, so anything above that will take precedence.)*

Comment: All of our AppService consumers make use of the code above with the 'EventHubConsumerClient' as far as we can find out. Could it be that the Azure Functions do this? Or could it be that this happens because people are using: https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/

Comment: Azure Functions using an event processor internally when an Event Hubs trigger is used; that will assert exclusive access to the Event Hub / Consumer Group.

Comment: We're making use of the Azure Function EventHub trigger of the .net 5.0 isolated functions. No specific EventProcessor's or anything. Just the default triggers for EventHubs to Azure Functions.

Comment: Yup; the trigger uses an event processor implicitly.

Comment: Ok that basically answers my question. Is there any reason why it works that way? I mean what is the reason for a function to lock the whole consumer group? In the end both functions and my own code keep track of their own position they are reading in the EventHub right?

Comment: I can't speak to why a processor was chosen for the Functions architecture.   The processors request exclusive access to a partition in order to facilitate coordination for load balancing between them; it serves as a safe guard to ensure the guarantee that "only one event processor will process a given partition".

Answer (score 0):

To add to the [Jesse's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162425/ajinkya) answer, I think the exception message is part of
the old SDK.
If you look into the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-event-processor-host#with-epoch), there 3 types of receiving modes defined there:

1. Epoch

> Epoch is a unique identifier (epoch value) that the service uses, to enforce partition/lease ownership.
> The epoch feature provides users the ability to **ensure that there is only one receiver on a consumer group at any point in time**...

2. Non-epoch:

> ... There are some scenarios in stream processing where users would like to create **multiple receivers on a single consumer group**. To support such scenarios, we do have ability to create a receiver without epoch and in this case we allow **upto 5 concurrent receivers on the consumer group**.

3. Mixed:

> ... If there is a **receiver already created with epoch** e1 and is actively receiving events and **a new receiver is created with no epoch, the creation of new receiver will fail**. Epoch receivers always take precedence in the system.

Comment: It's text returned by the Event Hubs service;  you should see the same message across SDK packages.   :)

Comment: Yes, but the Epoch is not described in the documentation of new sdk.

Comment: That is largely true; when we ran studies for the design of the new SDK we found that the term "epoch" was often confusing to folks due to its common association with time.   The SDKs moved to calling this the "owner level".   The legacy term is briefly discussed in [summary text](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.consumer.eventhubconsumerclient) for the consumer types. It's unfortunate that we haven't been able to influence the service text.   I'll take a follow-up to get this term included in the troubleshooting areas.